# Send GeoJSON request to Django with Ajax

Tags: python, leaflet

I want to use leaflet to send a GeoJSON to a Django view using Ajax.
I use this code:

```
var marker = new L.Marker([0, 0]);
var geojson = marker.toGeoJSON();
console.log(geojson)
```

`console.log` shows me this:

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {},
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            0,
            0
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to send this JSON to a Django view with Ajax. And I am using this Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    data: geojson,
    url: '{% url 'json' %}',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        //alert('sdf')
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('error')
    }
});
```

urls.py:

```
path('json', json1, name='json'),
```

view.py:

```
@csrf_exempt
def json1(request):
    print(request)
    return JsonResponse({'check': False})
```

But the output of this code is not shown correctly and it prints this error:

raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

How can I get access to the requested JSON?